# Reference request: second Chern class of P^2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, projective-space, characteristic-classes

I have heard that $c_2(T_{\mathbb{P}^2})=e(\mathbb{P}^2)$. What's the general result and where can I read about it? Thanks.

Comment: The general result is that the top Chern class and the Euler class (of the underlying real bundle) coincide. I'm sure it's in Milnor & Stasheff and Husemoller, but I don't have them with me at the moment and so can't give you a specific section.

Comment: @anomaly: you mean the underlying oriented real bundle, of course.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Yes, of course, thank you. (HLC: In case it isn't clear, a complex structure on a bundle orients the underlying real bundle.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general result is that for a complex compact manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ we have $$\chi_\text{top}(M)=c_n(T_M)                $$ Here $\chi_\text{top}(M)$ denotes the topological Euler class of $M$, the alternating sum $\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(-1)^ib_i$ of its Betti numbers $b_i=\operatorname {dim}_\mathbb Q H^i(M,\mathbb Q)$.
And $c_n(T_M)\in H^{2n}(M,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z$ is the top Chern class of the holomorphic tangent bundle of $M$.

It is remarkable that the left-hand side depends only on the  topological space underlying $M$ while the right-hand side takes into account the holomorphic structure of $M$.
Griffiths-Harris prove this theorem on page 416 of their [book](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Principles_of_Algebraic_Geometry.html?id=Sny48qKdW40C&redir_esc=y), and call it *Gauss-Bonnet Formula III*. The theorem also goes under the name  *Poincaré-Hopf*.
In your case ($M=\mathbb P^2_\mathbb C$) you will obtain the formula $1-0+1-0+1=3$, which can also be checked in a more elementary way (ask your little niece) .

Comment: Can't you say this a bit more generally, for an arbitrary complex vector bundle?

Comment: Yes, although then one has to be more careful not to conflate the Euler class and the Euler characteristic...